# CM Roman font in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, extrafont

For I can't use CM roman in ggplot.

This works:

```
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
  theme(text=element_text(size=16,  family="Times New Roman"))
print(a)
```

but this does not

```
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
  theme(text=element_text(size=16,  family="CM Roman"))
print(a)
```

When I run `fonts()` it tells me that CM Roman is one of the fonts.

Answer (score 0):

the font probably isn't registered yet.  run this first and try again:

```
library(extrafont)
font_install('fontcm')
```